# Tab Control blocking mouse scroll event C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a tab control that contains multiple tab controls. All of the tab controls were made using the winforms designer. The embedded tab controls each have `Chart` objects assigned them. These were created after the program was ran, and each chart was given three events:

```
chart.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler((sender, e) => this.Chart_MouseWheel(sender, e, chart, raw, condensed, bounds));
chart.MouseHover += new EventHandler(Chart_Hover);
chart.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler((sender, e) => this.Chart_Click(sender, e, chart));
```

For easy debugging, I added a simple `Console.WriteLine();` to each method to see which methods were actually being fired.

```
private void Chart_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e, Chart chart, DataTable raw, DataCondenser condensed, List<double> bounds)
{
    Console.WriteLine("a");
}

private void Chart_Hover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("b");
} 

private void Chart_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e, Chart chart)
{
    Console.WriteLine("c");
}
```

After hovering, clicking, and scrolling a lot, I can only get `b` and `c` to be outputted. For some reason the scroll event will not be picked up. I have a feeling this has to do with being inside a tab control.

Any ideas why this is happening?

EDIT:

Tried a small-scale version of this and the same thing is happening.

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Chart test = new Chart();
        test.Width = 500;
        test.Height = 500;


        test.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(Chart_Scroll);
        test.MouseHover += new EventHandler(Chart_Hover); //mousehover event for the tooltip to activate
        test.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(Chart_Click);

        tabPage3.Controls.Add(test);
    }

    private void Chart_Scroll(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("a");
    }

    private void Chart_Hover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("b");
    }

    private void Chart_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("c");
    }
```

The same issue occurred. `tabPage3` was a tabpage of a tabcontrol inside of a tab control.

EDIT 2:

so if I give the chart this event handler:

```
test.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(mouseEnter);
```

with the method:

```
private void mouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Focus();
}
```

it still doesn't work. However, if I use this:

```
private void mouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Chart)
    {
        Chart temp = (Chart) sender;
        temp.Focus();
    }
}
```

It will work, even if it's embedded in other controls.

Comment: Can you get a `Scroll()` event from your Chart if you add it **directly** to the Form (with no other controls present)?

Comment: @Idle_Mind Interesting. So if it was just the chart on the form, I still couldn't get it to scroll. I added a `MouseEnter` event handler to give to do `test.Focus()`, which then started picking up the scroll events.

Comment: Perfect.  Can you extend the Chart class and add the MouseEnter/Focus combo?  If not, we can explore other ways of making that "automatic" for all Charts in your app.

Comment: I think I got it to work properly now. I added an edit above. If the chart was exclusively on the form itself, using `this.Focus();` worked. If it was inside multiple chart controls, it would not work though. Checking to see if it was a Chart first fixed this problem. Thanks for the ideas @Idle_Mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wire up the MouseEnter() event and give the Chart focus with a one-liner like this:

```
test.MouseEnter += (s, evt) => { ((Control)s).Focus(); };
```